Submitting files via HTML to Google Forms
I just learned how to mock a Google Forms under my HTML forms and everything's working fine. Until... I have to upload files in my HTML and send it to my forms. With text input and other stuffs I just get my entry.somenumber while inspectioning Google Forms and everything works fine. What about uploading files?
If that's not possible. Is there a easy (and free) way that I can send files to my Google Drive folder via HTML?


<form id="contactForm" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdcBpysNoHZ-foYQA9zsxEM2sDvyg-yI0bRAjOtrjbW0Q6jjw/formResponse" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
  <input type="text" id="nome" name="entry.806066519" required>
  <br>
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="entry.1958672347" required>
  <br>
  <label for="fotos">Enviar Fotos (até 3 arquivos):</label>
  <input type="file" id="fotos" name="file" multiple accept="image/*">
  <br>
  <button type="button" id="submitBtn">Enviar</button>
</form>




1) To the best of my knowledge, you can't write an app script for file upload to Forms. 2) everything's working fine Has the relevant javascript been written yet? 3) Is there a reason why the HTML form connects to a Google Form? There's a lot of material for connecting HTML forms to a Google Sheet-has this been considered? 4) Though it doesn't answer your question directly, have you read Uploading File to Google Drive from External HTML without Authorization by @Tanaike.

@Tedinoz The question is not about using Apps Script. It's about "mocking" a Google Form. Let's say that the OP wants to customize the look and feel of a form but still submits the form data to Google Forms to take advantage of features like connecting to a spreadsheet or generating response graphs, among others. In this case, it looks like the OP is looking for an easy way to upload files to Google Drive and assumed that a File Upload question could be easily "mocked."

I don't think there is a simple way to "mock" a File upload question from Google Forms. It's worth mentioning that it's impossible to use Google Apps Script Forms Service or the Google Forms API to upload files "to Google Forms" as this operation is complex, first the file should be uploaded to a temporary space, then on form submission the file should be uploaded to Google Drive, then get the file URL, then add this URL to the Google Form response submissions store, then if there is a spreadsheet linked, include the URL in form submission entry to be added to the linked spreadsheet to finally add a new row with the form submission entry values.
To upload a file to Google Drive using an HTML form, create a Google Cloud project, enable the Google Drive API, and add the corresponding code to your HTML form.
Start by studying the following quickstart : https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/js
